# jQuery append dict to html, how to insert a auto-incrementing id from 1

Tags: php, html, jquery

How to insert a auto-incrementing `id` from 1 before `info.name` in jQuery? I use below code to get aggregated data, for example, each `quessionId` has many related `reasons`. Below is my partial code of `.js` code in jQuery:

```
function fmtQuestionsByID(id,callback){
    if(!DATA.questions[id] || !$('#card_'+id) )return;
    var project = DATA.projects[DATA.questions[id].projectId];
    if(!project)return;
    
    var issueQuestionLists = DATA.alltags.reduce(function(a,b){
        if(a[b['quessionId']]) {
            a[b['quessionId']].push({name:b['name'],color:b['color'],description:b['description'],reason:b['reason'],question:b['question'],issueId:b['issueId'],department:b['department'],_id:b['quessionId']})
        } else{
            a[b['quessionId']] = [{name:b['name'],color:b['color'],description:b['description'],reason:b['reason'],question:b['question'],issueId:b['issueId'],department:b['department'],_id:b['quessionId']}]
        }
        return a;
    },{});
    for(var i=0;i < DATA.questions[id].tags.length;i++){
        var lid = DATA.questions[id].tags[i];

        for(var l in issueQuestionLists){
            var lb = issueQuestionLists[l]
            for(var c=0;c< lb.length;c++){
                var lc = lb[c];
                if(lc._id == lid){
                    var info = lc;
                    console.log('info', info);
                    $('.tags_question').append('['+info.name+']' + info.description + '。' +  'Reason: '+info.reason+ '。' ||'[no data]' );
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

And I use below html to get above data

```
<div id="questioninfo">
    <span class="tags_question"></span>
</div>
```

In the console, I do have those dictionaries, but why the page only get one dict?

Thanks so much for any help.

Thanks so much for Swati's help, to change `.html` to `.append`.

Comment: Maybe because you have use `.html()` which removes other content inside div and add new one .Instead use `.append()`

Comment: Thanks so much, Swati, you saved my day!!!!!! Do you know how to insert an index with auto-incrementing id from 1? I will post a new question, thank you again for your help.

Comment: where you need to insert to your html generated ? You can use `c` variable which you have already defined in for-loop

Comment: before `'['+info.name+']'`

Comment: @Swati I can't use  `c`, if I have two dicts, and I will have two `id`s  of `[0,1, 2]` and `[0,1,2,3]`

Comment: Define a variable i.e : `var count=0;`(outside for loop)  then inside your `if(lc._id == lid){` do `count++` and then append it like this `$('.tags_question').append(count+'['+info.name+']'..`

Comment: My god!!! Why are you so excellent? Why don't you post your comments on the answer? I want to accept your answer!!!! Thank you Swati, you really really saved my day my week

Comment: @Swati I can't believe you know everything, do you know to let dicts with different color, i.e case color=1 set red, case color=2 set green when color = 3 set blue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63399119/jquery-display-list-dict-to-html-let-different-dict-with-different-color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a `variable` which will store the value of count and then whenever you need to print it first `increment` it and then add that as well with the data which you are already appending .So your code will look like below :

```
  var count = 0; //declare this 
for (var i = 0; i < DATA.questions[id].tags.length; i++) {
  //..other codes
  var lc = lb[c];
  if (lc._id == lid) {
    count++; //increment
    var info = lc;
    console.log('info', info);
    //add with other datas
    $('.tags_question').append(count + '[' + info.name + ']' + info.description + '。' + 'Reason: ' + info.reason + '。' || '[no data]');
  }
}
```

Comment: Another question, how to sort them by `questionID`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63399848/jquery-sort-append-dict-dynamically-by-key