# jQuery sort `.append()` dict dynamically by key？

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to sort `.append()` items dynamically by `questionsId`？ I use below code to get aggregated data, for example, each `quessionId` has many related `reasons`. Below is my partial code of `.js` code in jQuery:

```
function fmtQuestionsByID(id,callback){
    if(!DATA.questions[id] || !$('#card_'+id) )return;
    var project = DATA.projects[DATA.questions[id].projectId];
    if(!project)return;
    
    var issueQuestionLists = DATA.alltags.reduce(function(a,b){
        if(a[b['quessionId']]) {
            a[b['quessionId']].push({name:b['name'],color:b['color'],description:b['description'],reason:b['reason'],question:b['question'],issueId:b['issueId'],department:b['department'],_id:b['quessionId']})
        } else{
            a[b['quessionId']] = [{name:b['name'],color:b['color'],description:b['description'],reason:b['reason'],question:b['question'],issueId:b['issueId'],department:b['department'],_id:b['quessionId']}]
        }
        return a;
    },{});
    var d = 0;
    for(var i=0;i < DATA.questions[id].tags.length;i++){
        var lid = DATA.questions[id].tags[i];

        for(var l in issueQuestionLists){
            var lb = issueQuestionLists[l]
            for(var c=0;c< lb.length;c++){
                var lc = lb[c];
                if(lc._id == lid){
                    d++;
                    var info = lc;
                    console.log('info', info);
                    $('.tags_question').append(d + '['+info.name+']' + info.description + '。' +  'Reason: '+info.reason+ '。' ||'[no data]' );
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

And I use below html to get above data

```
<div id="questioninfo">
    <span class="tags_question"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Swati If you know how to sort them, please type here. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: insert more html pls

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov Hi, I use js to get data and display everything, no more html, we don't need html to help us.

Comment: which `key` you need to use here to sort values ?